# Scala implicits and type aliases

Tags: scala

Let's say I have the following piece of code:

```
object Potato extends App {

  type CoolString = String
  type AwesomeString = String

  def potato(string: String)(implicit coolString: CoolString, awesomeString: AwesomeString) = {
    s"$string is a string. Oh, but don't forget - $coolString and also $awesomeString"
  }

  implicit val ice : CoolString = "Really Cold Ice"
  implicit val awe : AwesomeString = "Awe inspiring object"

  potato("Stringerino")

}
```

This code fails with a problem

```
[error] ... ambiguous implicit values:
[error]  both value ice in object Potato of type => Potato.CoolString
[error]  and value awe in object Potato of type => Potato.AwesomeString
[error]  match expected type Potato.CoolString
[error]   potato("Stringerino")
```

Is such use of implicits impossible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is such use of implicits impossible?

Not only is it impossible, it is dangerous to rely on such a method taking in a type as general as `String` as an implicit. Think about it, any `String` instance in scope will be an eligible candidate to get passed into the method!

A type alias is just, well, a type alias, nothing more. To the compiler both `CoolString` and `AwesomeString` are merely `String`.

A better approach is to leverage Tagged Types. For example, this is a [tagged type using shapeless](http://www.vlachjosef.com/tagged-types-introduction/):

```
import shapeless.tag.@@

trait CoolString
trait AwesomeString

type ReallyCoolString = String @@ CoolString
type ReallyAwesomeString = String @@ AwesomeString
```

And then:

```
import shapeless.tag

def potato(string: String)(implicit coolString: ReallyCoolString, awesomeString: ReallyAwesomeString) = {
  s"$string is a string. Oh, but don't forget - $coolString and also $awesomeString"
}

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  implicit val ice = tag[CoolString][String]("Really Cold Ice")
  implicit val awe = tag[AwesomeString][String]("Awe inspiring object")

  println(potato("Stringerino"))
}
```

Yields:

```
Stringerino is a string. 
Oh, but don't forget - Really Cold Ice and also Awe inspiring object
```